# My python output is printing out twice and while I want it to print out once

Tags: python

So, I have this:

```
nums = []
N = 5
for n in range(N):
    numbers = int(input('Please enter an integer: '))
    nums.append(numbers)
avg = sum(nums)/5
print(f"The average is:", avg )

for v in nums:
    if v > avg:
        print("The numbers greater than the average are:\n", (v))
```

Which outputs something like the following:

Please enter an integer: 5

Please enter an integer: 4

Please enter an integer: 9

Please enter an integer: 7

Please enter an integer: 2

The average is: 5.4

The numbers greater than the average are:
9

The numbers greater than the average are:
7

---

However I was wondering if someone knew how to make the bottom part show up like this instead:

The numbers greater than the average are:

9 7

Comment: You need to accumulate the results as you find them, and then print only once, after the loop.  There are many examples of doing this available on line.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use list comprehension as followings:

```
...
avg = sum(nums)/5

...

print("The numbers greater than the average are:\n", *[i for i in nums if i > avg])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
nums = []
N = 5
for n in range(N):
    numbers = int(input('Please enter an integer: '))
    nums.append(numbers)
avg = sum(nums)/5
print(f"The average is:", avg )

g =[]
for v in nums:
    if v > avg:
        g.append(v)
print("The numbers greater than the average are:\n", *g)
```

### Output

```
Please enter an integer: 5
Please enter an integer: 4
Please enter an integer: 9
Please enter an integer: 7
Please enter an integer: 2
The average is: 5.4
The numbers greater than the average are:
 9 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the last part of your code use:

```
print("The numbers greater than the average are:")

for v in nums:
    if v > avg:
        print(v, end=" ")
```